# how sync dependency for gms and firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to android so please help me.

```
*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.0.4.*
>   *here is the code*

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'//show red underline at this line
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'//show red underline at this line
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please explain the problem in detail

Comment: kindly check now ...

Comment: The error itself is self explanatory, you need to update the services plugin or gms. The current versions specified are conflicting.

Comment: sorry its awkward to ask...but how to update

Comment: bcz there is no option for update in sdk manager..

Comment: Did you check the link ? You can use maven or Ivy or Gradle

Comment: suggest me detailed answer ,blog link or video link...if possible

Answer (score 0):

Update your versions in dependency for `com.android.support` and `com.google.firebase` like below: and Sync Project.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' // update version
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0' // remove duplicate entry with other version
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0' // update version

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'


    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Is it the same error? if yes, please connect to internet and sync, gradle will download necessary updated version. If some new error, then please update